# AlexNet doesn't converge in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently decided to migrate from MATLAB to Tensorflow. I started by creating the ALexNet model in Tensorflow. I want to train the AlexNet on my own data from scratch. (I have done this successfully in MATLAB using matconvnet). However, my model in tensorflow never converges. The loss and accuracy remain the same.
I save my data in a tfrecords file and read it and can verify that the data is loaded correctly. But I can't get why the model deosnt seem to train.
I am using Tensorflow 1.2.0 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is my code: Where 'val.tfrecords' is the tfrecords file containing my training date

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import cv2
from random import shuffle
import random as rand
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import scipy.misc
import math

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

# Initialize the weights with random numbers
def W_init (w_height,w_width,num_channels,num_filters,method = 'normal', W_name = 'w'):
    if method is 'normal': std =1
    if method is 'xavier': std = std = np.sqrt(2./(w_width*w_height*num_channels))
    return(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([w_height,w_width,num_channels,num_filters], mean=0.0, stddev=std),name = W_name,trainable=True))



# Create wrappers for simplicity

# Convolution layer
def conv_layer(x,W,b,stride,pad):
    x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [pad, pad], [pad, pad], [0, 0]], "CONSTANT")
    y = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,stride,stride,1], padding='VALID')
    y = tf.nn.bias_add(y,b)
    return y

# Pooling layer
def pool_layer(x,k,stride,method):
    if method is 'max':
        y = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize = [1,k,k,1], strides = [1,stride,stride,1], padding='VALID')
    if method is 'avg':
        y = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize = [1,k,k,1], strides = [1,stride,stride,1], padding='VALID')
    return y 


# Create a model AlexNet
def AlexNet(x,y_):

    # input
    x = tf.reshape(x,shape =[-1,224,224,3] )

    # conv1 + relu1
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer(x,W=W_init (11,11,3,96,method = 'xavier',W_name ='w1'), b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([96]),name='b1',trainable=True),stride=4,pad= 3))
    # maxpool1
    max1 = pool_layer(conv1,k=2,stride=2,method='max')


    # conv2 + relu2
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer(max1,W=W_init (5,5,96,256,method = 'xavier',W_name ='w2'), b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]),name='b2',trainable=True),stride=1,pad= 2))
    # maxpool2
    max2 = pool_layer(conv2,k=2,stride=2,method='max')

    # conv3 + relu3
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer(max2,W=W_init (3,3,256,384,method = 'xavier',W_name ='w3'), b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([384]),name='b3',trainable=True),stride=1,pad= 1))

    # conv4 + relu4
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer(conv3,W=W_init (3,3,384,384,method = 'xavier',W_name ='w4'), b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([384]),name='b4',trainable=True),stride=1,pad= 1))

    # conv5 + relu5
    conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer(conv4,W=W_init (3,3,384,256,method = 'xavier',W_name ='w5'), b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]),name='b5',trainable=True),stride=1,pad= 1))
    # maxpool5
    max5 = pool_layer(conv5,k=2,stride=2,method='max')

    # flatten the convolution output to use in fc layer
    max5_size = np.product([s.value for s in max5.get_shape()[1:]])
    max5_flat = tf.reshape(max5, [-1, max5_size ])    


    #  fc6 + relu6 +drop6
    fc6 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(max5_flat,tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([max5_size,4096],mean=0.0, stddev=2./math.sqrt(max5_size)),name='w6',trainable=True))+  tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4096]),name='b6',trainable=True) )
    drop6 = tf.nn.dropout(fc6, 0.5)

    #  fc7 + relu7 +drop7
    fc7 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(drop6, tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096,4096], mean=0.0, stddev=2./math.sqrt(4096)),name='w7',trainable=True))+ tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4096]),name='b7',trainable=True) )
    drop7 = tf.nn.dropout(fc7, 0.5)

    #  fc8
    fc8 = tf.matmul(drop7, tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096,23], mean=0.0, stddev=2./math.sqrt(23)),name='w8',trainable=True))+ tf.Variable(tf.zeros([23]),name='b8',trainable=True) 

    y = tf.nn.softmax(fc8) 
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))

    # Evaluate model
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))    
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)


    return cost,accuracy



train_filename = '/home/Documents/MyData/val.tfrecords'

# Model parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
Nimages = 1087
mean_image = np.load('mean_image_256.npy') # This is the 
n_input = 224*224*3 # img shape: 224*224*3
n_classes = 23
batch_size = 200 
Num_epochs = 1000
display_step = 3*batch_size

## Read the tfrecord file we've just created #############################################
# 1- Create a list of filenames: In this case there's only a single file 
train_data_path = train_filename


# TF graph Inputs and Placeholders
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,224,224,3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_classes])

# Define out loss and optimizer

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature = {'train/image' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'train/label' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/width' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

    # 2- Create a queue to hold filenames: To do so, we use tf.train.string_input_producer function which hold filenames in a FIFO queue.
    # it gets the list of filnames. It also has some optional arguments including  num_epochs which indicates the number of epoch you want to to load the data,
    # and shuffle which indicates whether to suffle the filenames in the list or not. It is set to True by default.

    train_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([train_data_path], num_epochs=None)
    val_filename_queue   = tf.train.string_input_producer([val_data_path], num_epochs=None)

    # 3- Define a reader and read the next record
    # For files of TFRecords we need to define a TFRecordReader with reader = tf.TFRecordReader().
    # Now, the reader returns the next record using: reader.read(filename_queue)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, train_serialized_example = reader.read(train_filename_queue)
    _,  val_serialized_example =  reader.read(val_filename_queue)

    # 4- Decode the record read by the reader
    # A decoder is needed to decode the record read by the reader.
    # In case of using TFRecords files the decoder should be tf.parse_single_example. it takes a serialized Example and a dictionary
    # which maps feature keys to FixedLenFeature or VarLenFeature values
    # and returns a dictionary which maps feature keys to Tensor values: features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
    train_features = tf.parse_single_example(train_serialized_example, features=feature)
    val_features = tf.parse_single_example(val_serialized_example, features=feature)

    # 5- Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
    # tf.decode_raw(bytes, out_type) takes a Tensor of type string and convert it to typeout_type.
    # However, for labels which have not been converted to string, we just need to cast them using tf.cast(x, dtype)
    train_image = tf.decode_raw(train_features['train/image'], tf.float32)

    # 6- Cast label data into int32 and Reshape image data into the original shape
    train_label = tf.cast(train_features['train/label'], tf.int32)
    train_label = tf.one_hot(train_label, n_classes)
    train_height = tf.cast(train_features['train/height'], tf.int32)
    train_width = tf.cast(train_features['train/width'], tf.int32)
    train_image = tf.reshape(train_image, tf.stack([train_height, train_width, 3]))



    # 7- Any preprocessing here ...
    train_image = tf.image.central_crop(train_image, 1)
    train_image = tf.image.resize_images(train_image, [256,256])
    train_image = tf.random_crop(train_image, [224, 224, 3])
    train_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(train_image)





    # 8- Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
    # Batching: Another queue is needed to create batches from the examples. You can create the batch queue using:
    # tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)
    # where capacity is the maximum size of queue, min_after_dequeue is the minimum size of queue after dequeue,
    # and num_threads is the number of threads enqueuing examples.
    # Using more than one thread, it comes up with a faster reading.
    # The first argument in a list of tensors which you want to create batches from.
    train_images, train_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([train_image, train_label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=3*batch_size, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=batch_size,allow_smaller_final_batch=True)




    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    cost,accuracy = AlexNet(x_,y_)

    # 9- Initialize all global and local variables

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op) 
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir = '/tmp/tf/foo', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    writer.flush()

    # 10- Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
    # Filing the example queue: Some functions of tf.train such as tf.train.shuffle_batch add tf.train.
    # QueueRunner objects to your graph. Each of these objects hold a list of enqueue op for a queue 
    # to run in a thread. Therefore, to fill a queue you need to call tf.train.start_queue_runners
    # which starts threades for all the queue runners in the graph. 
    # However, to manage these threads you need a tf.train.Coordinator to terminate the threads at the proper time.



    # Create a saver for writing training checkpoints.
    saver = tf.train.Saver()


    train_acc = np.zeros(Num_epochs)
    val_acc = np.zeros(Num_epochs)

    for epoch in range(Num_epochs):
        im_counter = 0

        for iter in range(Nimages/batch_size):
            im_counter+=batch_size
            # Get a training image batch  and  subtract mean
            t_img, t_lbl = sess.run([train_images, train_labels])
            t_img = (t_img - scipy.misc.imresize(mean_image, (224,224)))/255
            #t_lbl = to_onehot(t_lbl,n_classes)



            # Run session

            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x_: t_img, y_: t_lbl})

            # Display training results
            if (im_counter%display_step)==0:
                print "epoch " + str(epoch) +  " Processed images: " + str(im_counter) + "/" +str(Nimages)+", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Accuracy= " + \
                "{:.5f}".format(acc) 

        # After an epoch is trained, save model and run validation
        saver.save(sess, 'AlexNet_saved_model.ckpt')
        train_acc[epoch] = acc

        im_counter = 0


    print "Optimization Finished!"
    plt.plot(train_acc)
    plt.title('Training accuracy')
    plt.show()            
    # Stop the threads
    coord.request_stop()

    # Wait for threads to stop
    coord.join(threads) 
    sess.close()
```

Comment: Why are you converting from MATLAB instead of using the AlexNet provided in any handy model zoo?  That should fix whatever problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one error in your code:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(fc8) 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))
```

You should not apply *softmax* before calling `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) clearly states this:

> **WARNING**: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a `softmax`
>   on `logits` internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the
>   output of `softmax`, as it will produce incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually am applying softmax before softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits by mistake. I fixed that. But still getting the same behavior.